# DC 0-1V to 0-10V voltage amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have an Horiba gas analyzer having the analog out linear 0-1. My data logger (10 bit) has the input 0-10V. Of course, I can use like that but on higher ranges for analyzer gases the reading after A/D conversion is not accurate.
Can you give me an linear voltage amplifier circuit drawing from 0-1V to 0-10V? I have some practice in electronics and I think I can do it by myself. The circuit can be for one channel.
Thank you,
 Tiberiu

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called a "[signal conditioner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_conditioning)." These are readily available commercially.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be too judgmental, but that's a pretty crappy data logger (10 bits).

A simple gain of 10 amplifier will do it. 10 bits with 1V input means that 1 bit is (input referred) 1mV so a single-supply op-amp with an offset voltage << 1mV will not add significant error. I put a pretty good one in there, but even an LM324 won't typically be all that bad (maybe one bit). Similarly the resistors R1 and R2 should have a ratio that's within (say) 0.05% to not add much error, but using 0.1% parts won't add much error typically, or even 1% and adjust for the error digitally or with a trimmer. R3, R4 can be 1% or 5% and C1-C3 can be X7R ceramic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2favIaC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Spehro, you are the best! well, the company I'm working with selected the datalogger (of course the cheapest   one, less than $100) to be use with an ultra expensive analyzer. now I have to fix the problem, but thanks to you I'm gonna make it.